# Error libtorch_python.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, torch, python-3.7

I'm trying to implement fastai pretrain language model and it requires torch to work. After run the code, I got some problem about the import torch._C

I run it on my linux, python 3.7.1, via pip: torch 1.0.1.post2, cuda V7.5.17. I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pretrain_lm.py", line 7, in <module>
    import fastai
  File "/home/andira/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .basic_train import *
  File "/home/andira/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/basic_train.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .torch_core import *
  File "/home/andira/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/torch_core.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .imports.torch import *
  File "/home/andira/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/imports/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .torch import *
  File "/home/andira/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/imports/torch.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch, torch.nn.functional as F
  File "/home/andira/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: libtorch_python.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I tried to run this line:

```
from torch._C import *
```

and got same result

```
ImportError: libtorch_python.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked `/home/andira/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib` and there are only `libcaffe2_gpu.so` and `libshm.so` file, and I can't find libtorch_python.so either. My question is, what is actually libtorch_python.so? I've read some of article and like most of it talked about *undefined symbol*, not *cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory* like mine. I'm new at python and torch so I really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My problem is solved. I'm uninstalling my torch twice

```
pip uninstall torch
pip uninstall torch
```

and then re-installing it back:

```
pip install torch==1.0.1.post2
```

Comment: I have been using TensorFlow for a while, but after the release of Detectron2, by FAIR, I decided to give it a go and also start getting my hands dirty with PyTorch. Very upsetting to find the same issue as you did and even more upset with the way it was fixed. Anyways, thanks for posting.

Comment: This is a lifesaver 

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `pytorch` 1.4.0. For which, upgrade the `pytorch` library using the following command,

```
pip install -U torch==1.5
```

If you are working on Colab then use the following command,

```
!pip install -U torch==1.5
```

Still facing challenges on the library then install `detectron2` library also.

```
!pip install detectron2 -f https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu102/torch1.9/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into this error when I accidentally overwrite `pytorch` with a different channel. My original `pytorch` installation is from `pytorch` channel and in a later update it was overwritten with the one from `conda-forge`. I got this error even if the version is the same. After reinstalling `pytorch` from `pytorch` channel, the error is gone.